# Сохранение нескольких json файлов в zip архив

Tags: java, android, zip

Есть вот такой метод:

```
public boolean saveZip(File zipFile) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, zipFile.getAbsolutePath());
        boolean result = false;

        if (!zipFile.exists()) zipFile.getParentFile().mkdirs();

        try {
            ZipOutputStream zipOutputStream = new ZipOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(zipFile)));

            JsonWriter writer = new JsonWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(zipOutputStream, "UTF-8"));
            // Запись таблицы DB_TABLE_NAME в архив
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "ЗАПИСЬ: " + DB_TABLE_NAME + ".json");
            Cursor cursor = getAllData(); // основная таблица данных;
            {
                ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(DB_TABLE_NAME + ".json");
                zipOutputStream.putNextEntry(entry);
                writer.beginArray();
                while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                    writer.beginObject();
                    writer.name(_ID)
                            .value(cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(_ID)));
                    writer.name(COLUMN_PARENT)
                            .value(cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_PARENT)));
                    writer.name(COLUMN_THING_NAME)
                            .value(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_THING_NAME)));
                    writer.name(COLUMN_DESCRIPTION)
                            .value(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_DESCRIPTION)));
                    writer.name(COLUMN_DATE)
                            .value(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_DATE)));
                    writer.name(COLUMN_ISBOX)
                            .value(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_ISBOX)));
                    writer.endObject();
                }
                writer.endArray();
                cursor.close();
                writer.close();
                zipOutputStream.closeEntry();


            }
          // Запись таблицы DB_TABLE_NAME_FOTOS в архив
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "ЗАПИСЬ: " + DB_TABLE_NAME_FOTOS + ".json");
            cursor = getAllDataNameFotos();
            List<String> fotos = new ArrayList<>();
            {
                ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(DB_TABLE_NAME_FOTOS + ".json");
                zipOutputStream.putNextEntry(entry);
                writer.beginArray();
                while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                    writer.beginObject();
                    writer.name(_ID)
                            .value(cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(_ID)));
                    writer.name(COLUMN_ID_THING)
                            .value(cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_ID_THING)));
                    writer.name(COLUMN_NAME_FOTO)
                            .value(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_NAME_FOTO)));
                    fotos.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_NAME_FOTO)));
                    writer.name(COLUMN_DESCRIPTION_FOTO)
                            .value(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_DESCRIPTION_FOTO)));
                    writer.name(COLUMN_DATE)
                            .value(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_DATE)));
                    writer.endObject();
                }
                cursor.close();
                writer.endArray();
                zipOutputStream.closeEntry();
            }

          // Сохраняем фотки в архив
            {
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Сохраняем фото в архив");
                for (String fotoName : fotos) {
                    File fileFoto = new File(fotoDir, fotoName);
                    if (fileFoto.isFile()) {
                        ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(fileFoto.getName());
                        zipOutputStream.putNextEntry(entry);
                        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                        int length;
                        InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(fileFoto);
                        while ((length = inputStream.read(buffer)) > -1) {
                            zipOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, length);
                        }
                        inputStream.close();
                        zipOutputStream.closeEntry();
                    }

                }
            }

            // запись таблицы DB_TABLE_NAME_ATTR
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "ЗАПИСЬ: " + DB_TABLE_NAME_ATTR + ".json");
            cursor = getAllDataNameAttr();
            {
                ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(DB_TABLE_NAME_ATTR + ".json");
                zipOutputStream.putNextEntry(entry);
                writer.beginArray();
                while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                    writer.beginObject();
                    writer.name(_ID)
                            .value(cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(_ID)));
                    writer.name(COLUMN_NAME_ATTR)
                            .value(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_NAME_ATTR)));
                    writer.endObject();
                }
                writer.endArray();
                cursor.close();
                zipOutputStream.closeEntry();
            }

          // запись таблицы DB_TABLE_NAME_LIST_ATTR
            cursor = getAllDataNameListAttr();
            {
                ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(DB_TABLE_NAME_LIST_ATTR + ".json");
                zipOutputStream.putNextEntry(entry);
                writer.beginArray();
                while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                    writer.beginObject();
                    writer.name(_ID)
                            .value(cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(_ID)));
                    writer.name(COLUMN_ID_THING)
                            .value(cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_ID_THING)));
                    writer.name(COLUMN_ID_ATTR)
                            .value(cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_ID_ATTR)));
                    writer.name(COLUMN_DESCRIPTION_ATTR)
                            .value(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_DESCRIPTION_ATTR)));
                    writer.endObject();
                }
                writer.endArray();
                cursor.close();
                zipOutputStream.closeEntry();
            }

            zipOutputStream.close();

        } catch (IOException e){
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, e.toString());
            return result;
        }
        result = true;
        return result;

}
```

Проблема в том что метод `writer.close()` полностью закрывает и `zipOutputStream`, и дальше метод 'zipOutputStream.closeEntry()' не срабатывает. А если убрать метод `writer.close()`, то работает, но файлы в архиве пустые получаются.

Comment: Возможно, имеет смысл делать writer.flush() перед каждым zipEntry, а writer.close() перед закрытием zipOutputStream.close()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В итоге нашел два способа решения проблемы:

1) Для каждого нового файла json, создавать новый объект `writer`, в конце создания файла использовать метод `writer.flush()` (как и подсказали в комментариях), только ни в коем случае не использовать метод `writer.close`.

2) Использовать свой класс наследованный от `ZipOutputStream`. Вот какой класс у меня получился:

```
    private class MyZipOutputStream extends ZipOutputStream{
    public MyZipOutputStream(OutputStream os) {
        super(os);
    }
    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException {
        super.closeEntry();
    }
    public void closeclose() throws IOException {
        super.close();
    }
}
```

Получается что объект при использовании метода `close()` закрывает `Entry`. То есть при закрытии `writer`, не происходит полное закрытие 'zipOutputStream'. Только отдельно добавлен метод `closeclose()` который и будет осуществлять полное закрытие zip-файла.